# Tensorflow: TFLiteConverter (Saved Model -> TFLite) in SSD_mobilenet_v2_2

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-lite

I have installed tensorflow 2.3.1, my ssd_mobile_net_v2_2 was downloaded from https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/ssd_mobilenet_v2/2. I want to convert this model to tf_lite version. My code is:
[image]

But error occurs:

tensorflow.lite.python.convert.ConverterError: :0: error: loc("Func/StatefulPartitionedCall/input/_0"): requires all operands and results to have compatible element types
:0: note: loc("Func/StatefulPartitionedCall/input/_0"): see current operation: %1 = "tf.Identity"(%arg0) {device = ""} : (tensor<1x320x320x3x!tf.quint8>) -> tensor<1x320x320x3xui8>
[image]

it seems I need to set the input-data-type, but I don't know how to do that.

Thanks a lot for your replying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution from: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/42114#issuecomment-671593386

note: tf-nightly==2.4

Answer (score -1):

I looked at [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/41877) and found this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model("ssd_mobilenet_v2_2",signature_keys=['serving_default'])
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.experimental_new_converter = True
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]
model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(model)
```

I'm using `tensorflow-nightly` I didn't tried with another version

Comment: thanks for your reply. But what's the tf-nightly version you are using? I have tried tf-nightly==2.3.0.dev20200513 but the error show:

Comment: can you try to run my code? Maybe the ssd_mobilenet model is new, so it will have many incompatible

Comment: I've got this version `2.4.0-dev20200812`. And when I try your code I've got the same error.

Comment: in your converted lite model, what's the  input_shape?

Comment: by run: input_shape = input_details[0]['shape']     print(input_shape)

Comment: The input is `[1,1,1,3]` so it didn't worked as you needed I'm sorry I used [neutron](https://netron.app/) to look at it

Comment: From [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35736) it seems that you should use `tf.compat.v1.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph` to correct your problem I haven't tried myself but it's the last thing I found sorry

Comment: I have solved this problem. Later I will push the complete code below my this question. Thank you very much~~